# Postfix restrictions seemingly ignored

Tags: postfix, email-server

I'm currently trying to block a specific "from" domain that is getting forwarded from postfix to my personal e-mail.

In the mail.log file I get something of the sort:
`Apr 29 14:42:49 <censored> postfix/qmgr[7509]: 19F743F71E: from=<n07411ac6de-c3fc1a24b4404633-<name>===<domain>.com@bounce.twitter.com>, size=106187, nrcpt=1 (queue active)`

I've tried preventing this through a headers check with
`/^From:.*bounce.twitter.com/ REJECT`
in /etc/postfix/header_check along with the following line in the main.cf file
`header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks`

Following a postmap and reload the mail is still forwarded.

I tried to use `bounce.twitter.com REJECT` in the /etc/postfix/sender_access along with the changes in main.cf with:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access

[...]

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        reject_unauth_destination,
        check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf,
        check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
```

Following various things online. Again with all of these changes I still get the forwards.

I am very clearly not understanding something here but I don't quite understand why these mails are still going through despite these. The current full main.cf (minus comments) is below. I've applied minor censoring of domain names just in case:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

append_dot_mydomain = no

#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        reject_unauth_destination,
        check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access,
        check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf


milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
smtpd_milters = local:/opendkim/opendkim.sock
non_smtpd_milters = local:/opendkim/opendkim.sock

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = <mydomain>.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, <mydomain>.com, localhost.com, , localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

virtual_alias_domains = <anotherDomain>.com <yetAnotherDomain>.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Comment: This is often accomplished with a tool such as `sieve` or even `spamassassin`, but you haven't told us anything else you may have on your server to achieve your goal.

Comment: At the moment I don't have anything else (relay related) aside from opendkim (which isn't a factor here) as I thought this could be done through postfix. But if that's not the case then I'll have a look at sieve or spamassassin.

Comment: I'm not saying it isn't, just that there wasn't any other info about the server and it isn't the usual way for a mail server that has these other tools.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try `smtp_header_checks` instead of `header_checks` (which is done by `cleanup`).